# How to enter Hex color in Gpick?

Tags: linux

Can not find any way to enter Hex color code in Gpick.

I'm sure there is a way - but simply can not find it. Have looked all around.

One can enter RGB, HSV, HSL etc.

Yes. I can convert the Hex to decimal RGB but that takes too much brain power for a task like that ;)

(Sorry for dumb question)

Answer (score -1):

If Gpick does not have a feature like entering Hex Color code directly, you can use online tools to convert HEX to RGB like this https://www.rgbtohex.net/hextorgb/. I guess you do not use online tool. If you use an online tool, it does not take too much brainpower :)

Comment: Yes. I use online tools from time to time – but find desktop tools better to work with, - esp. when one want to pick color from screen as well. Also wrote a tool in python for cli but that has it limitations. I settled on KColorChooser. It is much simpler - but at least it is possible to enter hex color. Have still not found a way to do it in Gpick which makes me believe there is no way - which in turn is uber weird imo. :P